# How to use jQuery to select a dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I was wondering if it’s possible to get jQuery to select an `<option>`, say the 4th item, in a dropdown box?

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I want the user to click a link, then have the `<select>` box change its value, as if the user has selected it by clicking on the `<option>`.

Comment: do your options have a value?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

How about

```
$('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
```

**Example:**

```js
$('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

---

for modern versions of jquery you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `.attr()`

```
$('select>option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
```

**Example:**

```js
$('select>option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: imo this shouldn't even work; the selected state of an option should be triggered by changing the state of the select itself instead :)

Comment: `selectElement.selectedIndex = index;` is what Jack means.

Comment: @rlemon, i understand, but `selectedIndex` cannot be used for multiple selection when `multiple` attribute is used. And the normal (*html*) way to set selected elements is the `selected` attribute of the `option` elements.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli The normal way is actually to set the `selected` property of each corresponding `options` element to `true` (and optionally the rest to `false` explicitly). Multiple selections are pretty nasty actually :)

Comment: (*i think that is what i said, too*)

Comment: There's a subtle difference, though that said, your current answer doesn't deal with multiple either.

Comment: @jack, it does not as the OP does not need it. I was responding to your comment that "*imo this shouldn't even work; the selected state of an option should be triggered by changing the state of the select itself instead*" and i am saying that this concept could not deal with all valid usages of a select element. (*if you are arguing on the W3C specs, then that is another issue, and glad to discuss it on the W3C mailing lists*)

Comment: Sorry for that, I should remind myself not to write foot-in-mouth comments when I'm still sleeping :( I didn't realize that `new Option() instanceof Node`, so assuming `.attr('selected')` maps to the property, it be kosher; of course, the argument for using `.selectedIndex` still holds for regular dropdowns :)

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't fire an 'onchange' event.

Comment: It is not triggering 'onchange' event. Any hacks for that too??

Comment: @sunnyiitkgp the `onchange` event is never triggered when the value is changed programmatically. You could add a `.trigger('change')` at the end to also fire the event (*although it will fire regardless of the value having actually changed*)

Comment: I ran into an issue where the dropdown value wouldn't "visually" change until I performed a .change() on the target. However, since I had an event tied to the dropdown, it would cause the event to also trigger. Using .prop('selected', true) solved the issue!

Answer (score 162):

The solution:

```
$("#element-id").val('the value of the option');
```

Comment: it doesn't set the `selected` option in the HTML.

Answer (score 56):

HTML select elements have a [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select#attr-selectedIndex) property that can be written to in order to select a particular option:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 3); // select 4th option
```

Using plain JavaScript this can be achieved by:

```
// use first select element
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]; 
// assuming el is not null, select 4th option
el.selectedIndex = 3;
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't fire an 'onchange' event.

Comment: @GuyKorland This happens with none of the other answers either, demonstrated [here](http://jsbin.com/ehahug/1/); if you want an event to fire, you have to do it manually.

Comment: @Jack Is there a short way? The only way I found: 
var fireEvent = function(selectElement){
                        if(selectElement){
                            if ("fireEvent" in selectElement){
                                selectElement.fireEvent("onchange");
                            } else {
                                var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                                evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
                                selectElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: @GuyKorland jQuery exposes `.trigger()` for that, but since you're already doing this with code it would be easy to also call the change handlers yourself.

Answer (score 41):

I would do it this way

```
 $("#idElement").val('optionValue').trigger('change');
```

Comment: $("#idElement").val('optionValue').change() could also work

Comment: finally an answer that also considers the event! @Ullullu indeed, your version works just as well.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way is `val(value)` function:

```
$('select').val(2);
```

And to get the selected value you give no arguments:

```
$('select').val();
```

Also, you if you have `<option value="valueToSelect">...</option>`, you can do:

```
$('select').val("valueToSelect");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/48Gkv/)

Comment: Also worked $('#SelectCtrlId').val('ValueToSelect');

Answer (score 25):

if your options have a value, you can do this:

```
$('select').val("the-value-of-the-option-you-want-to-select");
```

'select' would be the id of your select or a class selector. or if there is just one select, you can use the tag as it is in the example.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following code if you want to select an option with a specific value:

```
$('select>option[value="' + value + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: $('select').val(value); 
Why so serious? ;)

Comment: @Zee The answered code allow multiple selections too.

Answer (score 6):

```
 Try with the below codes. All should work. 
    $('select').val(2);
    $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
    $('select>option[value="5"]').prop('selected', true);
    $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $("select option:contains(COMMERCIAL)").attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: None worked. Although that is probably due to some other error

Answer (score 3):

I prefer nth-child() to eq() as it uses 1-based indexing rather than 0-based, which is slightly easier on my brain.

```
//selects the 2nd option
$('select>option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: The "1-based index" is better when manipulating things with dates. Saves me from a lot of troubles. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

One caveat here is if you have javascript watching for select/option's change event you need to add `.trigger('change')` so the code become.

```
 $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
```

because only calling `.attr('selected', 'selected')` does not trigger the event

Answer (score 3):

With '' element usually we use 'value' attribute. It will make it easier to set then:

```
$('select').val('option-value');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#mySelectElement option')[0].selected = true;
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

answer with id:

```
$('#selectBoxId').find('option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$selectedindex=4
```

If you want to randomise options, you could always do something like this:

```
$0selectedindex=Math.floor((Math.random()*($0.length-1)+1)
```

Whilst the 2nd lies outside scope of your questions, it serves to illustrate how 1st could be applied / amended as req.

Comment: (note - $0 serves to represent $, but I'm relatively new to Python so still familarising myself with differences in relation to some of this syntax - but selectedindex still avail. in jquery world - hope this helps.