# JQuery get selected text dropdown text jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

Helo,

I want to get selected text from dropdownlist using jquery..

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem you've faced ?

Comment: Already answered! at least do a search before you ask:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this:

```
$("#yourdropdown option:selected").text();
```

Comment: I see that you copy answers a lot...

Answer (score 9):

it would be something like that using just pure jquery

```
$("#idofyourdropdown option:selected").text();
```