# Use jQuery to create a link which selects a drop down option

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, html-select

This question comes off another question here: [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

I am following this example however, I don't understand the demonstration in the top answer

`$('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);`

http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/CWvwn/

None of the answers provide the code for the link so that a user can click it to change the drop down option. What would a link look like to use this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is to use `nth-child` pseudo-selector like this:

```
$('select::nth-child(2)').attr('selected', true);
```

Or, if the select is properly done, like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

You can select via the `value` attribute:

```
$('select>option[value=4]').attr('selected', true);
```

---

Since you will surely want to have more of the links, it's handy to define a function:

**JS**

```
function showOptWithValue(which) {
    $('select>option[value=' + which + ']').attr('selected', true);
}
```

Now, to bind this function to your link, you can either use `onclick`:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onClick="showOptWithValue(3); return false;">The Link</a>
```

Or assign the click handler with pure jquery:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">The Link</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    showOptWithValue(3);
    return false;
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle with some working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FY3tz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CWvwn/1983/)

```
$('.link').click(function() {
   $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so does `$('.link').click(function() {
   $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
});` need to be written out for every option in a drop down list?

Comment: it depends of what functionallity you want to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//html

<a id="myLink" href="#">My link</a>
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
</select>

//js

$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>


    <a id="btn-change-option" data-option="2" href="#">Change to 3</a>

    <script>

    $("#btn-change-option").click(function(){

         // get option to select from the data attribute of your link
         var optionToSelect = $(this).data('option');

         $('select>option:eq('+optionToSelect +')').attr('selected', true);

    })

    </script>
```