# Selecting value in dropdown as default

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to select on load a certain option from dropdown to show as selected option(blue background).
My jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //ddLiss it he id of the dropdown
   //North Side is one of the options that i need selected on document load. 
  $("#ddList").select("North Side");
});
```

When i run this in code, I get the drop down with all values but "North Side" doesn't show as selected one. Please let me know how I can fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on value:

```
$('#ddList').val('North Side');
```

BY text:

```
$("#ddList option").each(function() {
if($(this).text() == "North Side") {
  $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

Comment: Damn you're fast! haha +1

Answer (score 1):

`$("#ddList option:contains('North Side')").prop("selected",true);`

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$('select>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
```

Source: [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and set the value "North"  in your dropdown.

```
$("#ddList option[value='North']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

All dropdowns have a "SelectedValue" and a "SelectedText" option.

You have to set the *`value`* of the dropdown to the value of "North Side".

You can do this via:

`$("#ddList").val("1");` // '1' being the *value* of the bound list

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select>
        <option>please select</option>
        <option value='1'>northside</option>
        <option value='2'>south</option>
    </select>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option:contains("northside")').prop('selected',true);
});
```

[check this fiddle [check this fiddle][1]](http://jsfiddle.net/XyTtu/51/)