# Change selected option in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My html is

```
<select name="one_day_per_month" id="one_day_per_month" style="width: 200px">
  <option value="false" selected>No</option>
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

The page is wrapped with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {...}
```

I can change the value by using

```
$("#one_day_per_month").val("true")
```

The value is updated, but the dropdown list does not change in the browser does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Asked and answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option

Comment: Add `.trigger('change');` after updating the value.

Comment: It is changed http://jsfiddle.net/La1p70eL/. Are you wrapping your code in the `$( document ).ready(function() {...}` ?

Comment: @HanletEscaño yes I am

Comment: Is that what you want? What I have in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Yep. That is my goal.

Comment: Just realised (this was not my page) that the selectmenu is a jQueryUI widget. After updating the value I need to use `$("#one_day_per_month").selectmenu( "refresh" );`

Answer (score 1):

Try this call trigger with change to achieve your requirement.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#one_day_per_month").val("true").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="one_day_per_month" id="one_day_per_month" style="width: 200px">
  <option value="false" selected>No</option>
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably running before the HTML tags for your select element is loaded.
You have two ways to fix it:

1. Put your script at the end of your HTML right before the  tag
2. Embed all your code in $(function () { /* your code here */}); This makes sure that your code runs after the HTML is entirely loaded and parsed in the browser.