# change selecteed option based on returned HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 select elements with an id of `ticket_customer` and `ticket_contact`

This JQuery code is on the same page:

```
$("#ticket_contact").change(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    var html = $.ajax({
        url: "?getCustomerSequence=1&sequence="+val+"",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ticket_customer').val(data);
        }////////////function html////////
    })/////////function ajax//////////
});
```

so when i change selection, it will run this code:

```
if($_GET["getCustomerSequence"] == '1') {
    echo '1';
    exit();
}
```

which just returns `1` with absolutely nothing else on the page

i want to be able to select the option with the value of `1` (which is returned in the HTML) but its not selecting anything

there is an option in the `#ticket_customer` select element with the value of `1`

I have tried doing an `alert(data);` in the JQuery in the success part which returns `1` too.

alternatively, rather than returning the HTML, would there be a way to return an array in PHP and read this in using JQuery and then getting the correct value from the PHP array using JQuery

Comment: You might be better off having the PHP return a JSON string instead of just plain text. You'll also be able to include and parse more information.

Comment: but why you need to use ajax while you can change the selection of select 2 directly after change selet1 ??

Comment: its getting live data so i dont want to refresh the screen if there is new data available. @Lix i can return a JSON string in PHP but how do i access this from the JQuery?

Comment: @charlie - you'll want to include a [`dataType `](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) attribute to your `$ajax` function and specify 'json' - then in your success callback, you can access it like a normal JSON object: `data.whatEverYouWant`. For the PHP, just echo a `json_encode` function

Comment: in the PHP, i guess i will need to echo the json_encode($return) part?

Comment: can you post an answer please then i can accept! :) also, where does the json need to be specified? (sorry im not great with jquery - more of a PHP person :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be seen here: [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

In your success function, do:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#ticket_customer > option:eq(' + data + ')').prop('selected', true));
}
```