# Contact form 7 pass variable as new select option

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a cf7 select field:

```
[select* dropdown_2 id:pakett class:dropdown_2 first_as_label "Choose" "Option1" "Option2" "Option3" "Option4"]
```

On the same page there are 4 different buttons. When I click on any of these buttons I would like the correct option to be chosen from the field.

```
<a href="#"><button>Choose Option1 from select</button></a>
<a href="#"><button>Choose Option2 from select</button></a>
<a href="#"><button>Choose Option3 from select</button></a>
<a href="#"><button>Choose Option4 from select</button></a>
```

I'm thinking of a solution for buttons:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('pakett').val($("#pakett option:first").val());">
```

but it is not changing the options. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is the following JQuery for each ID and option:

```
$('#link').on('click', function(){
    $('select.dropdown_2>option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
});
```

found from: [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)