# Simulate Mouse Click on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

My Wordpress theme interacts with WooCommerce so that when a user selects a specific product variable from a drop-down a particular price is shown for their region.

This works fine when a user manually selects the drop-down, however, I'm trying to speed up the process by pre-selecting the appropriate option for the user based on a browser cookie (or lack of one).

For instance, if the user hasn't entered their region their browser will not have a cookie I've named "pc-entered" and the following jQuery script will run:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li.product').each( function() {
        /*If no region set by cookie*/
        if( document.cookie.indexOf("pc-entered=") < 0) {
            /*Set downdown to generic*/ 
            $(this).find("#pa_region").val('generic');  
        }
    });
});
```

This works, successfully pre-selecting the correct 'generic' dropdown option automatically.

Unfortunately, and this is where I'm stuck - although the dropdown is correct the price isn't auto-populating like it does when a user manually selects their region.

E.g.

**1) When auto-populated using my script:**

**2) When user selected:**

[image]
[image]

I've tried replacing this in my script:

```
$(this).find("#pa_region").val('generic');
```

With the options listed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option), however, they don't seem to work in this case. I've also tried firing the script after all other scripts on the page and even delaying the script running with a timeout function but nothing seems to be working.

My test site is [here](http://dtodd.co.uk/).

**TLDR -** Why is my jQuery script not populating the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$(this).find("#pa_region").val('generic');` you are only changing the HTML value (text) of dropdown.

You need to attach the event handler which will trigger the change to the function where you change the value.

```
function changeValue(){
  $("#pa_region").val('generic');
  $("#pa_region").trigger('change');
}

$( "#pa_region" ).change(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

This is the way on how to solve it.

I also made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rkkb3jh/2/) so you can test it.

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes sense that I'm only changing the HTML. Quick question, in your JSFiddle the function is triggered by clicking the button. How could I get the function to trigger when the page loads whilst retaining my existing each function?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could just add the trigger in document.ready function. https://jsfiddle.net/2rkkb3jh/4/