# How to auto-select the first option in a dropdown list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble auto-selecting the first option in a dropdown list.

I've tried using attr and val function (see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/57ufay7o/) jdfiddle link for an example) and it just wouldn't work. As a a test, my example has an  alert code that displays the .text() for the first option and this works fine. So my selector is working.

Thanks a lot!

sample HTML code:

```
<select id="rt" name="rt" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a fruit -</option>
  <option value="20270">Apple</option>
  <option value="20271">Banana</option>
  <option value="20273">Grapes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="rs" name="rs" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a car -</option>
  <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
  <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
  <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```

sample JS  code:

```
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
    alert("rt: "+$("#rt option:first-child").text());
    $("#rt option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
    //$("#rt option:first-child").val("blank");
});
```

Comment: So you mean, selecting a car should auto-select the first fruit??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use selector val method to set the value

```
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
    alert("rt: "+$("#rt option:first-child").text());
    $("#rt").val($("#rt option:first-child").attr("value"));    
});
```

or simply

```
$("#rs").on("change", function() {       
    $("#rt").val($("#rt option:first").val());    
});
```

The below snippet will do what exactly you want

```js
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
    $("#rt").val($("#rt option:first").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rt" name="rt" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a fruit -</option>
  <option value="20270">Apple</option>
  <option value="20271">Banana</option>
  <option value="20273">Grapes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="rs" name="rs" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a car -</option>
  <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
  <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
  <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('select>option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option) this is what you are looking for it seems.

Answer (score 1):

try with `$('select[name=rt] option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');` second option to select because first option `- Select a fruit -` is default selected so no any change in `select`

and if you select first option so use `option:eq(1)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#rs").on("change", function() {
    //$("#rt option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
    $('select[name=rt] option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rt" name="rt" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a fruit -</option>
  <option value="20270">Apple</option>
  <option value="20271">Banana</option>
  <option value="20273">Grapes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="rs" name="rs" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a car -</option>
  <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
  <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
  <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `first-child`, you need to use `eq()`.

Below code will always auto-select first fruit whenever you select any car from the dropdown:

```js
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
  $("#rt option:eq(1)").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rt" name="rt" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a fruit -</option>
  <option value="20270">Apple</option>
  <option value="20271">Banana</option>
  <option value="20273">Grapes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="rs" name="rs" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a car -</option>
  <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
  <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
  <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
    alert("rt: "+$("#rt option:first-child").text());
    $('#rt').html($("#rt option:first-child").text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#rs").on("change", function() {
    alert("rt: "+$("#rt option:first-child").text());
    $("#rt").val("blank");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$('select>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will select the first element of the `#rs` after you select one from `rt`.  I believe this is what you want.  I suspect the names are mixed up (as most forms go from top to bottom). If you desire the reverse, just comment.

```js
$("#rt").on("change", function() {
 $('#rs').find('option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true)
});
```

```html
<select id="rt" name="rt" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a fruit -</option>
  <option value="20270">Apple</option>
  <option value="20271">Banana</option>
  <option value="20273">Grapes</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="rs" name="rs" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="blank" selected="selected">- Select a car -</option>
  <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
  <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
  <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#rs").val($("#rs option:first").val());
   });
</script>
<select id="rs" name="rs">
   <option value="20226">Toyota</option>
   <option value="20227">Chevy</option>
   <option value="20228">Mazda</option>
</select>
```