# Drop-down menu initialization with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In the 'success' function of an AJAX call I initialize the selected value of a drop-down menu like so:

```
$('#mdCivilite').val (data[0].civilite);
```

data being an array.

This works smoothly with Firefox (v. 62.0.3): the drop-down menu displays correctly the text matching the value.

With Chrome (v. 67.0.3396.87), it does **not** work, i.e. the text displayed is that of the first element of the menu array.

What is it I do wrong?

Edition:

1) The drop-down menu is preloaded with JSON data:

```
 "FR":
 {
   "1" : "M.",
   "2" : "Mme",
   "3" : "Mlle"
 }
```

Now,for instance, wether  data[0].civilite  be 1, 2 or 3, the text displayed will be "M.".

The amazing thing is it has worked satisfactorily with Firefox for years.

2) Looking up for possible explanations I also checked here:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option) and re-tried for the umpteenth time other ways, e.g.:

```
$('#mdCivilite').prop('selectedIndex', data[0].civilite);
```

to no avail.

Comment: The line of code you've shown is fine by itself, but it depends on exactly what the value of `data[0].civilite` is and what the available options within the HTML of the select are.

Comment: Please see the newly edited post.