# how to set a select option value using jquery and select search lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

***how to select an option value form select dropdown list using jquery?
I am using a select option list with bootstrap plugin and select-search plugin but choosing is not a activated . . .***

```js
  $().ready(function(){
      // To style only selects with the selectpicker class
      $('select').selectpicker();
      $('#numbers').val(3);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--***************select search plugin********-->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
<select name="numbers" id="numbers">
<option>Why Not appears?</option>
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

I would like to th

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use jquery to select a dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh the selectpicker if you want to change the value after you created the selectpicker.

```
$('#numbers').selectpicker('val', 3);
```

But on page load, you only have to turn the order of your jquery.

```
$('#numbers').val(3);
$('select').selectpicker();
```

If you are trying to change multiple values on different selects, you can

1. call the selectpicker API (`$('#numbers').selectpicker('val', 3);`) multiple times
2. change all values with pure jquery and than refresh the selectpicker

   $('#first').val(3);
   $('#second').val(4);
   $('select').selectpicker('refresh');

Here is the source https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804479

Comment: There's no reason to use refresh. That method is *only to add / remove / disable options*. The OP should use `val` as stated in my answer.

Comment: You did not, it should be `.selectpicker('val', 3);`

Comment: I did. On pageload there is no reason to call it.

Comment: refresh worked just fine for me due to that i have more than one drop down menu in my application with the same problem and using $('select').selectpicker('refresh'); //solved them all . . . thanks all of you

Comment: You can call the `$('SELECTOR').selectpicker('val', VALUE);` every time you change a value. That's cleaner than refreshing since 2 lines > 1 line

Comment: because when you first answered with refresh i was impressed a lot but when you changed the answer i was a little upset . . . any way many thanks

Comment: I've edited and now it's back. However, the pure selectpicker solution looks a bit cleaner. Anyways, thanks for marking it back ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but you are overriding it when you initialize the picker. Instead, set the value and then initialize the picker OR **use the picker API** to do so:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').selectpicker();
      $('#numbers').selectpicker('val', 3);
  });
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').selectpicker();
      $('#numbers').selectpicker('val', 3);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--***************select search plugin********-->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
<select name="numbers" id="numbers">
<option>Why Not appears?</option>
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

This happens because the interface to that component changes once you initialize it to a picker. If you'd like to use `selectpicker` API, you need to use `.selectpicker('val', 3);`

[Read More](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval)

Comment: This works perfectly fine on page load. However, if you ever want to change the value after the init, you need to call the refresh function

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer and showed how to update post load.

Comment: You are calling the Val on the select element. This would change all selects. You need to call it on the #numbers

Comment: That is *likely* true, but the OP initialized like this, so who am I to assume?

Comment: The OP calls the init of selectpicker on all select and than try’s to change the value of #numbers.

Comment: Again that may be true, but you are assuming he has more than one picker.

Comment: That’s my personal opinion but I think that it would be better to give examples that work regardless of the code the OP has. If he copy and pastes your answer, he might be surprised, if he has more than one SP and all of them are changing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no selectpicker() function in your code, so jquery is not executing further. I have commented on it and its working fine.

```js
$().ready(function(){
      // To style only selects with the selectpicker class
      //$('select').selectpicker();
      $('#numbers').val(3);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--***************select search plugin********-->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
<select name="numbers" id="numbers">
<option>Why Not appears?</option>
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: He wants to keep the selectpicker. Why did you remove it?

Comment: I didn't remove it, I commented on it just to show him that there is no existence of  selectpicker() function in his code and hence it is stopping the next lines of script from executing.

Comment: That is not correct. His code does have it from bootstrap-select lib.