# How do you select a specific item from a dropdown list using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

The current code I have is as follows:

```
function SetDefaultCarrier(orderCarrier) {
    $("#carrierdropdown option:contains(" + orderCarrier + ")").attr('selected', true);
}
```

The issue is that this will select the first option found in the list which contains the string `orderCarrier`. For instance, if `orderCarrier` is "UPS IG", the function will sometimes select the value "UPS IG C" since the former is a substring of the latter. How do I make it only select an exact match?

Comment: Use `.val(orderCarrier)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/how-to-use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option

Comment: @Jasen Oh, how dumb I feel. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jQuery to select a dropdown option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/how-to-use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the following is what I was looking for:

```
function SetDefaultCarrier(orderCarrier) {
    $("#carrierdropdown").val(orderCarrier).attr('selected', true);
}
```

Comment: The correct way to set the selected attribute is to use the [jQuery .prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/), like so: `$("#carrierdropdown").val(orderCarrier).prop('selected', true);`